# Rename a column with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to rename a specific column in my R script using the colnames function but with no sucess so far.

I'm kinda new around programming so it may be something simple to solve.

Basically, I'm trying to rename a column called `Reviewer Overall Notes` and name it `Nota Final` in a data frame called `notas` with the codes:

```
colnames(notas$`Reviewer Overall Notes`) <- `Nota Final`
```

and it returns to me:

```
> colnames(notas$`Reviewer Overall Notes`) <- `Nota Final`
Error: object 'Nota Final' not found
```

I also found in [this post][1] a code that goes:

```
colnames(notas) [13] <- `Nota Final`
```

But it also return the same message.

What I'm doing wrong?

Ps:. Sorry for any misspeling, English is not my primary language.

Comment: Can you provide the output for `names(notas)`? Also, can confirm that `notas` is a data.frame? The output for `str(notas)` will be useful as well.

Comment: Here it is: 
`code`
> names(notas)
 [1] "Assessment Name"                  "Applicant First Name"             "Applicant Last Name"              "Applicant Email"                 
 [5] "Applicant Completed Date"         "Review URL"                       "Reviewer First Name"              "Reviewer Last Name"              
 [9] "Reviewer Email"                   "Assigned Competencies"            "Reviewer Overall Rating"          "Reviewer Overall Score (numeric)"
[13] "Reviewer Overall Notes"          `code`



And it is acctualy a `tibble`! Sorry about that!

Comment: Here is the > str(notas)
tibble [860 × 13] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)

Unfortunately there is a lot of personal data there that I cannot share. =( 
,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want

```r
colnames(notas)[colnames(notas) == "Reviewer Overall Notes"] <- "Nota Final"
```

(@Whatif's answer shows how you can do this with the numeric index, but probably better practice to do it this way; working with strings rather than column indices makes your code both easier to read [you can see *what* you're renaming] and more robust [in case the order of columns changes in the future])

Alternatively,

```r
notas <- notas %>% dplyr::rename(`Nota Final` = `Reviewer Overall Notes`)
```

Here you *do* use back-ticks, because tidyverse (of which `dplyr` is a part) prefers its arguments to be passed as symbols rather than strings.

Comment: It Worked! Thank you!

There is any tips where I can learn more about it? Why use colnames twice?

Comment: The first time `colnames(notas)` is referring to the names of the object you are trying to change. The second use (inside the square brackets) is a logical test `colnames(notas) == "Reviewer Overall Notes"` which will return TRUE in one location and FALSE for the rest. You could explore this behaviour by typing `my_var = c(1,2,3,4)` and checking what `my_var[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]` returns. You would get the same if you typed `my_var[my_var == 3]`

Answer (score 4):

Why using backtick? Use the normal quotation mark.

```
colnames(notas)[13] <- 'Nota Final'
```

This seems to matter:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4)
colnames(df)[1] <- `b`
```

> Error: object 'b' not found

Comment: Thank you! Worked! 

I get used to use the backtick because portuguese have a lot of special characters, good to know that it may be in the way.

Answer (score 2):

**You should not use single or double quotes in naming:**

I have learned that we should not use space in names. If there are spaces in names (it works and is called a non-syntactic name: And according to Wickham Hadley's description in Advanced R book this is due to historical reasons:

"You can also create non-syntactic bindings using single or double quotes (e.g. "_abc" <- 1) instead of backticks, **but you shouldn’t**, because you’ll have to use a different syntax to retrieve the values. The ability to use strings on the left hand side of the assignment arrow is an historical artefact, used before R supported backticks."

To get an overview what syntactic names are use `?make.names`:

```
make.names("Nota Final")
[1] "Nota.Final"
```